# React Native in-app-purchases: how to test in TestFlight?

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

I've added in-app-purchases to my React Native app, and I've been testing them locally using sandbox tester accounts. When I go to `Settings -> App Store -> SANDBOX ACCOUNT` on my iPhone, it says `This account will be only used for testing your in-app purchases while developing locally. Your existing App Store account will be used for TestFlight apps.` When I try testing the IAPs with TestFlight, nothing seems to load.

**What I Want To Know:** How do you make the IAPs work with an App Store account on TestFlight the same way they do with a sandbox account locally?